# Color detection in AS3 possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Hey, i was wondering what do the AS3 experts would do to detect a color with the webcam (red) and draw a sprite on those color boundaries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the pixel data in [BitMap](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) (Or more correctly, the associated [BitMapData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html)) to write your own filter, or you could use a [BitmapFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/BitmapFilter.html).

You should be able to capture a bitmap from the webcam by drawing [Video](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Video.html) to a bitmap you create (use [draw()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) to draw the current video image).

So this should get you a bitmap and a way of detecting pixels in it. Now you can change the bitmap to add your own graphics (or put them in a sprite that is on top of the bitmap). Show the bitmap on screen after you've changed it, and repeat this for every frame :-)

See http://www.kasperkamperman.com/blog/flash-code/as3-apply-bitmap-filters-to-a-webcam-image/ for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the parade but perhaps it can help others. I just put online a class called **ChromaTracker** that probably would do what you are looking for.

Basically, you feed the `ChromaTracker` object with a color and a `DisplayObject` (it can be a webcam feed assigned to a `Video` object) and it will detect where in the `BitmapData` the color can be found. You can then fetch a `Bitmap` of the detected pixels, a Rectangle object of the outer boundary formed by all detected pixels or a `Point` object representing the center of the blob of detected pixels.

With that information, it would be very easy for you to add your `Sprite` on top of the detected pixels. You can download the class plus a demo on my site : http://cote.cc/projects/chromatracker. There is also a full API documentation.